# Creating objects in Model.js, NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, mongoose

In my model.js (using mongoose) , I am initially creating 40 objects in model.js which are to be used in the entire program. No other function in any file creates more objects but only updates the existing ones.

My model.js

```
var TicketSchema =  mongoose.model('Tickets', TicketSchema);

for(let i = 1;i<=40;i++)
{
    var new_ticket = new TicketSchema({ticket_number:i});
    new_ticket.save(function(err, ticket) {
   });
}
```

Problem is I noticed there were much more objects than 40 after some time. I wanted to know if model.js runs more than once during execution or is it just due to repeated calling of npm run start and then closing the server?

Also is there way better way of creating objects initially which are to be used for the entire program?

Comment: Does anything ever *delete* those tickets from the DB? Do you check whether they're there before you create more? Or do you just create another 40 every time it starts?

Comment: No, tickets are not deleted in any  function. I need to just use 40 intially created objects in my entire execution

Comment: Then is it a surprise that there are more over time? It sounds like you want more of a *migration* pattern, where one-off initialisation is needed. Or just *check first* and only create if needed.

Comment: No I wanted to know is it just due to server closing and running again? When I host the code, then would it happen again?

Comment: Yes, every time the server starts that file is imported and 40 new tickets are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create new 40 documents every time you start the server. You can use this function to avoid creating if the records already exist by checking count.

```
const TicketModel =  mongoose.model('Tickets', TicketSchema);

const insertTicketNumber = async () => {
  try {
    const count = await TicketModel.countDocuments({});
    if (count) return;
    await TicketModel.create(
      [...Array(40).keys()]
        .map(i => i + 1)
        .map(number => ({ ticket_number: number }))
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: This function isnt adding items, I am getting an empty list

Comment: Did you call the function?